# Word 2007 make hyperlink style show in headings

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, styles

In one of my templates I need to have my hyperlink style show in headings.
I am using ms built in heading styles (modified).

The styles are applied to text, not paragraphs (by omitting the last character in the heading line from the selection the style is applied to) - so I am not tied to headings for para numbering, and the para numbers appear in the TOC - the headings record importance rather than structure.

Can anyone help with changing the precedence of the 2 styles,

or perhaps just removing the "no underline" from the heading style- so links are at least underlined?

I see the hyperlink style overrides other styles, including a heading style I imported by accident (which seems to be a paragraph style...aargh)

(I use other heading styles in other templates, some tied to numbering  so I do not want it to b uinversal!)

Thanks for any help!